# Golang processing wrong package names

Tags: go

I have a directory `view_test` with two files: `main_test.go` and `test.go`.

Both files start with

**main_test.go**:

```golang
package view_test

import (
```

**test.go**:

```golang
package view_test

import (
```

Now when I try to test with `go test` I get:

> found packages view (main_test.go) and view_test (test.go) in /foo/internal/resources/view_test

Seems like there are some unknown assumptions where go starts clobbering together package names. Could someone enlighten me what these are?

Comment: Files intended for testing must have a `_test.go` suffix. `test.go` does not qualify for that. I'd also avoid naming packages using `_test` suffix.

Comment: That's fair - still would be interesting how go thinks there is a view package?

Comment: I don't know, but if you change the folder name and all package names to `view`, it'll work. It'll also work if you keep `view_test` and rename `test.go`. Anyway, I'd avoid using `_test` package name suffix, and follow the test file naming requirement.

Comment: @abergmeier presumably `package view` is inferred from `package view_test` in a *test* file (`main_test.go`) but then it conflicts with the package declaration from the *non-test* file (`test.go` [as icza already pointed out test files must end in `_test.go`, `test.go` without the underscore is not enough]). You can see the code compile if you change the non-test file's package from view_test to view, then it will match the inferred package.

Answer (score 3):

The _test suffix in test files is special. From `go help test`:

> Test files that declare a package with the suffix "_test" will be compiled as a separate package, and then linked and run with the main test binary.

This feature exists so you can enforce black box tests. Normally tests are defined in the same package as non-test code, so tests have access to unexported identifiers. If that's not desired (i.e. because you want to make sure that tests only use the public API), tests can be declared in a *_test package instead. It's an exception to the rule that all go files in a directory must declare the same package name.

As pointed out in the comments in your case this leads to a package named "view" in the context of tests, and a package named "view_test " in the context of production code. That's the wrong way around and therefore causes multiple defined packages in the same directory.

Don't use the _test suffix for production code to fix the issue.